# passing dynamic values to xml file -flex fusion charts

Tags: xml, apache-flex, fusioncharts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                  xmlns:components="com.fusionwidgets.components.*">

    <components:FusionWidgets FCChartType="AngularGauge" FCDataURL="data/energyMtd.xml"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

and energyMtd.xml file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chart decimals="2"  palette="2" autoScale="1" paletteThemeColor="BDBDBD" showBorder="0" basefontColor="000000" 
    toolTipBgColor="BFBFBF" gaugeFillMix="{dark-10},{light-70},{dark-10}" gaugeFillRatio="3" 
    pivotRadius="6" gaugeInnerRadius="60%" tickValueDistance="10" showTickValues="1" tickValueStep="2" 
    placeTicksInside="0" placeValuesInside="0" showToolTip="1" baseFontSize="9" adjustTM="0" 
    pivotFillColor="000000" dataStreamURL="" gaugeStartAngle="225" gaugeEndAngle="-45" 
    gaugeOriginX="100" gaugeOriginY="98" gaugeOuterRadius="75" numberSuffix="kW" upperLimit="100" 

lowerLimit="0">

  <colorRange>
    <color minValue="0" maxValue="100" code="bbbaba"/>
  </colorRange>

  <dials>
    <dial value="0" rearExtension="10" baseWidth="10" bgColor="000000"/>
  </dials>

</chart>
```

how do i pass upperLimit="", dial value="" and maxValue="" values in colorRange dynamically from the flex side. i need these 3 values to plot on the angle gauge fusion chart

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chart gaugeOriginX="100" gaugeOriginY="98" gaugeOuterRadius="75" numberSuffix="kW" 

upperLimit="100"lowerLimit="0">

  <colorRange>
    <color minValue="0" maxValue="100" code="bbbaba"/>
  </colorRange>
  <dials>
    <dial value="0" rearExtension="10" baseWidth="10" bgColor="000000"/>
  </dials>
</chart>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem that you need to change the code a bit.

fw.FCDataXML = xml.toString();
fw.FCRender();

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:BorderContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                  xmlns:components="com.fusionwidgets.components.*"
                  creationComplete="init();">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.net.URLLoader;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        protected var xmlLoader:URLLoader;
        [Bindable]
        protected var xml:XML;

        /**
         * 
         */
        protected function init():void
        {
            xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parse);
            xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("data.xml"));
        };

        /**
         * 
         * @param   event
         */
        protected function parse(event:Event):void
        {
            xml = event.target.data;
            xml.ignoreWhitespace = true;
            xml.ignoreComments = true;

            xml.chart.@upperLimit = 100;
            xml.chart.dials.dial.@value = 0;
            xml.chart.colorRange.color.@maxValue = 100;

            fw.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(xml);
        };
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <components:FusionWidgets id="fw" FCChartType="AngularGauge" />
</s:BorderContainer>
```

I think you should check the component's documentation for more details about how it handles the data provider.

Good luck,
Rob

////////////////////////////////////

Hi,

after you loaded the XML file in to an XML object you can set the attributes' and elements' values.

For instance:

```
xml.chart.@upperLimit = 100;
xml.chart.dials.dial.@value = 0;
xml.chart.colorRange.color.@maxValue = 100;
```

I hope this is what you need,
Rob

Comment: Hi, even if i modify as u said. am facing the same problem. it is not executing the code after the line xml = event.target.data inside the parse(event) function

Comment: Hi. Have you checked your component's (or the one it extends) documentation?

Comment: Hi. i changed little bit of code. ie. i have given var xml:XML = XML(event.target.data); and when i give Alert(xml.toXmlString()).

Comment: it will display the data from xml file. now how i need to update few values in it.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds good. Try to amend the attributes the way I said, it should be fine. Let me know how it works.

Comment: Hi Rob, what i changed is that in <components:FusionWidgets id="fw" FCChartType="AngularGauge" FCDataXML="{xml}"/> coz i have anyhow loaded the xml file and able to get the contents. giving FCDataUrl is not required.

Comment: now when i run the app it shows "Error in Loading Data". i have appended values as u said

Comment: When you trace the value of the xml object what do you see?

Comment: HI, am able to update the xml file now. the only doubt i have is how to use that updated xml file.

Comment: When i use that xml file as <components:FusionWidgets id="fw" FCChartType="AngularGauge" FCDataXML="{xml}"/> it shows "No data to display".

Comment: Hi Sushma, have you read the documentation of the component? I reckon you will find something about it's dataproviders.

Comment: hey Rob, its working fine now. thank u. your code works fine except for few changes. instead of xml.chart.@upperLimit = 100; i gave xml.@upperLimit = 100; it gets updated and fw.FCDataXML = xml.toString(); fw.FCRender(); it works perfectly

Comment: Hi, now instead assigning 100 to xml.@upperLimit;
and 0 to xml.dials[0].dial.@value; i want to give values which i obtain from web service 'http://localhost.../?wsdl'. how do i go ahead

Answer (score 1):

Angular gauge only accepts XML data. It does not accept ArrayCollection.

Please check if you are converting the XML to String before passing.

Also you can enable the debug mode of the Gauge to see more details of the issue